# Regex to match XML comments

Tags: regex

I am looking for a Regex to match comments in XML documents:

```
<root>
<!-- 
    match this 
-->
<but>not this</but>
<!--
     and also this
-->
</root>
```

I've tried `<!--[^(-->)]*-->`, which only matches single line comments, and `<!--[\s\S\n]*-->` which matches non-commented nodes as well.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The regex you're looking for would be:

```
<!--[\s\S\n]*?-->
```

Explanation:

```
 <!--               All comments must begin with this
     [\s\S\n]       Any character (. doesn't allow newlines)
             *      0 or more of the previous thing ([\s\S\n])
              ?     As few of the previous thing as possible while still matching
               -->  All comments must end with this
```

If you have a comment inside a comment this will have issues though:

> **`<!-- Documentation`**
> **`This program documents itself using comments of the type <!--  -->`**
> `-->`

*Highlighted in bold means a match*

Comment: This exact expression didn't work for me, but this did: <!--[\s\S\n]*?-->.  Giving you the green check box for pointing out the "?" though, and the thorough explanation.

Comment: @DanSolovay I'll edit it to include your discovery of that Visual Studio quirk.

Comment: This will not work if the comment doesn't start at the beginning of line. like: `<div> <-- comment -->`. The `\n` is useless in the character class, `[\s\S]` stands for **any** character, including newline.

Comment: @Toto yes... I wrote this answer a while ago and returning to it I am perplexed by it working for 6 people even though it uses `^` and `$`. Regarding `[\s\S\n]`, see the above comment by the OP saying that adding the `\n` was necessary for their regex tool.